# Adding a section to a PE file, change Entry Point to the new section and execute any code

Tags: c++, c, portable-executable

I am working on a PE file packer and I can succesfully encrypt the .text section of an executable, change its entry point and add a new section. The newly added section will take care of decrypting the .text section and then jump to the original entry point.

Now, I would like to go a little bit further and execute more code in the new section. I can do pretty much everything I want, but if I call an external function (**cout** from **iostream** for example), the modified executable will crash while attempting to execute an illegal instruction. The disassembly of the stub in the new section looks like this :

```
.newsec:0042C020                 push    ebp
.newsec:0042C021                 mov     ebp, esp
.newsec:0042C023                 push    offset loc_40EB50
.newsec:0042C028                 mov     eax, ds:dword_40E0B0
.newsec:0042C02D                 push    eax
.newsec:0042C02E                 call    loc_41A350
.newsec:0042C033                 add     esp, 8
.newsec:0042C036                 pop     ebp
.newsec:0042C037                 retn
```

The line at address **0x42c033** will jump in the .text section but the code there is unrelated to what std::cout should do.

To help you help me, the code added in the new section is in a file stub.h/cpp :

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/OPT:NOREF")
#pragma optimize( "", off )
#pragma section(".stub",read,write,execute)

__declspec(code_seg(".stub"))
void hello_test()
{
    std::cout << "hello world";
}

__declspec(code_seg(".stub"))
void default_stub_start(void) {
    __asm {
        call hello_test

        mov eax, 0x400000 //oep
        jmp eax
    }
}
```

Then, the entire .stub section will be copied as is in the new section that I added to the executable. The compilation runs smoothly but the modified executable will crash, as I explained above. If I remove the line

```
std::cout << "hello world";
```

and replace it with some basic maths, it works fine.

My question is : how can I use external functions without breaking the executable ?

Comment: You are calling functions of the runtime and the linker bind them to you stub, but, unnfortunately, that are in the encrypted section... ;-)

Comment: @frankie If I do not encrypt the section, the problem still occurs though.

Comment: I think this is because your added section has been manipulated and will be located at a wrong address. Anyway consider that the common runtime, and its libraries, will always be binded in the standard text section that you will crypt. To work your stub have to be a complete standalone program with no calls to the main one. You may consider a static link to OS functions not related at any runtime library for the stub, but you need anyway some wrapper code. The point is **avoid any call to functions binded in the crypted section**. Means also that you cannot use streams or standard I/O.

Comment: I forget to tell that even if using direct OS calls statically linked you will use the jump table located in the PE. Be sure to have not crypted the **IAT** (Import Address Table) or you'll get the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot this question but actually found the solution months after having asked it. The problem here is that one must manually link to external functions, because their addresses are not known at run-time once the code is unpacked into memory.

To do this, one should do the following:

- Walk the Process Environment Block to iterate on the linked list of loaded libraries.
- Locate the library kernel32.dll and walk its export table, for instance to get the addresses of GetProcAddress and LoadLibrary.
- Use the API resolved before to load and resolve any other API.

For more information, the Chapter 10 of "The Rootkit Arsenal" is a must-read.